# Navigation in react-native does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

im trying to open up a different screen in my react app but i get an error:

> "The component for route 'Profile' must be a React compononent."

this is the App.js file:

```
    import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
    import {StyleSheet, View, Button, AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
    import Profile from '../AwesomeProject';

    export default class App extends React.Component{
        render(){
            return(
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Button style = {styles.button} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')}/>
                </View>
            );
        }
    }

    const screens = StackNavigator({
        Home: {screen: App},
        Profile: {screen: Profile}
    })

    AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => screens);
```

This is the Profile.js file:

```
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Image, TextInput} from 'react-native';

export default class Profile extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I did not include styles to shorten up the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a valid way to import your `Profile` component unless you're exporting it from an `index.js` file.

import Profile from '../AwesomeProject';`

So, try: `import Profile from '../AwesomeProject/Profile';` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You import **Profile** component from wrong location.

On App.js

```
import Profile from '../AwesomeProject'; // Change this line to the right profile component location
```